# Test on userform textbox entry is failing

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a userform with textboxes txtTF1 – txtTF30 where odd numbers are a start date and even numbers are end dates. I’m using a calendar date picker and a (correctly functioning) logical test to help ensure the inputs are dates. I also want a logical test on the inputs to make sure I don’t have overlapping dates.

The code below correctly spots date overlap until it runs into textboxes that are intentionally left blank. Those blanks are set to vbnullstring when the form initializes. At this point something triggers the message box saying there is an overlap on the next to last set of dates even when I can see that is not true.

Debug.Print is showing that the last set of dates in the userform is not loading into the variables.

I’m not sure where/how this test breaks down. Any thoughts?

```
Sub OverlapCheck

Dim i as Long
Dim CheckDate1
Dim CheckDate2
Dim CheckDate3

For i = 2 To 28 Step 2

    CheckDate1 = Controls("txtTF" & i).value
    CheckDate2 = Controls("txtTF" & (i + 1)).value
    CheckDate3 = Controls("txtTF" & (i - 1)).value

    ‘stop test if next date is blank
    If Not IsDate(CheckDate2) Then Exit For

    ‘if a valid date range is entered then check to see if the next date is an overlap
    If IsDate(CheckDate1) And IsDate(CheckDate3) Then

        If CheckDate1 >= CheckDate2 Then   
            MsgBox ("Dates " & CheckDate1 & " and" & CheckDate2 & " overlap"), vbOKOnly
            frmRLVL.Show

        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Possibly not germane to your problem but in your last iteration of the loop you are looking at txtTF27, txtTF28 and txtTF29.

Comment: the idea is that the next start date should be after the previous end date, correct? So txtTF3 > txtTF2 > txtTF1?

Comment: @SJR - correct, and a good point. I will want to address that.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman - Yes. the next start date should be after the previous end date. The dates should describe a continuous time frame. The end users are entering dates and amounts on multi year leases.

Comment: When you say "last set of dates in the userform is not loading into the variables. " you mean when i=28?

Comment: @Foxfire - I should have been clearer on that point. In the case where I'm having trouble the userform data is ending when i = 12. The variables that print with the last debug.print statement is i = 10. The message box also captures the i = 10 info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work with the addition of CDate() in the for/next statement. I'm still not sure why this makes it work on the last set of dates when input data ends where 2>i>28. At this point I'm calling it a win.

```
For i = 2 To 28 Step 2

    CheckDate1 = Controls("txtTF" & i).value
    CheckDate2 = Controls("txtTF" & (i - 1)).value
    CheckDate3 = Controls("txtTF" & (i + 1)).value

    If Not IsDate(CheckDate3) Then Exit For

    If IsDate(CheckDate1) And IsDate(CheckDate2) Then

        CheckDate1 = CDate(CheckDate1)
        CheckDate2 = CDate(CheckDate2)
        CheckDate3 = CDate(CheckDate3)

        If CheckDate1 >= CheckDate3 Then
            MsgBox ("Dates " & CheckDate1 & " and" & CheckDate3 & " overlap"), vbOKOnly
            frmRLVL.Show

        End If
    End If
Next
```